# selenium: use my local cookie to test website behind login?

Tags: selenium, cookies

On my computer, can I login to my web app, grab the cookie values, and have my selenium script use it to test the web app without having to login?

Is it also possible to modify the cookie expiration after logging in on my computer so that the cookie will won't expire when the selenium tests are running?

Is it possible to avoid having to write additional selenium logic to use the login form? If not, does it raise a cookie expired exception so that I know I need to re-login?

What about testing cookieless session webapps like Meteor.js?

Answer (score 0):

Using `.NET` I know you can set the `cookies`, or at least retrieve them.  Try placing your `cookies` there.

```
driver.Manage().Cookies = Your_Cookie_Object_Here;
```